# I tried to find the encode of a string by using a simple logic. it works for the file which was stored in C:\\f.txt but not for C:\\subfolder\\f.txt

Tags: c, utf-8, file-handling, utf-16

if String_GetEncoding returns 0 means it's UTF-8, 1 means UTF-16BE, 2 means UTF-16LE, 3 means UTF-32BE, otherwise UTF-32LE. the logic works fine. but when the file inside a subfolder or when I place multiple files together in the same file. it does not work correctly at all times.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
//  findEncode("C://UTF-8_TestCase//TestCase.txt");      //-->Not Working
  findEncode("C://utf.txt");      //-->Working
}

int findEncode(char *fname){
     char str[50];
     FILE *fr;
     fr=fopen(fname,"r");
     fscanf (fr, " %s", str) ;
     fclose(fr);
     if(String_GetEncoding(str) == 0){
        printf("UTF-8");
     } else if(String_GetEncoding(str) == 1){
        printf("UTF-16BE");
     } else if(String_GetEncoding(str) == 2){
        printf("UTF-16LE");
     } else if(String_GetEncoding(str) == 3){
        printf("UTF-32BE");
     } else {
        printf("UTF-32LE");
     }  
}

int String_GetEncoding(char *string)
  {
    int c, i = 0, flags = 0;
    while (string[i] | string[i + 1] | string[i + 2] | string[i + 3])
      flags = (c = string[i++]) ? flags | ((!(flags % 4) &&  c > 0x7F) << 3) : flags | 1 | (!(i & 1) << 1) | ((string[i] == 0) << 2);
    return (flags & 1) + ((flags & 2) != 0) + ((flags & 4) != 0) + ((flags & 8) != 0);
  }
```

Comment: Do basic error checking. In particular, check the return value of `fopen` and `fscanf`. On failure call `perror` to get a more detailed error message.

Comment: "_0 means it's UTF-8, 1 means UTF-16BE ..."_  If you use an `enum` you'd never have needed to explain that or even remember it yourself.

Comment: "_the logic works fine_" - Occam's Razor suggests otherwise.  It is implausible that the logic is affected by filesystem organisation.

Comment: I've never encountered a file system that uses `//` as [directory separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) - you're lucky enough `C://utf.txt` even finds a file.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a sufficient description of the problem. (And "does not work correctly at all times" is even worse!) Provide a file for which you don't get the expected result, provide the result you get for that file, and provide the expected result for that file and the reason that's what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
findEncode("C://utf.txt");
```

but should have either:

```
findEncode("C:/utf.txt");
```

or

```
findEncode("C:\\utf.txt");
```

Forward slash is not an escape delimiter and does not itself need to be escaped, `"//"` is *literally* two forward slashes.

You read the input using:

```
fscanf( fr, " %s", str ) ;
```

but `fscanf()` works with single byte characters - I think it will not behave as you expect for multi-byte encodings. You should read the raw data using `fread()` having explicitly opened the file in *binary* mode: `fopen( fname, "rb" )`. Using `fread()` in any event avoids a buffer overrun that is inevitable with `fscanf()` if your file has lines longer than 50 characters.

`String_GetEncoding()` itself - I am not even going to begin to fathom that logic, but the expression increments `i`, but also uses `i` - are you certain that has the semantics you intended? The code is "too clever" for its own good - perhaps, break it down and comment it?

Moreover `String_GetEncoding()` makes no attempt to avoid overrunning the buffer. The loop iteration will cease when four consecutive bytes all have zero value - I am not not sure how that can work. Especially when `str[]` is not initialised in the first instance.

Comment: Missed (at least) one issue: Accesses `string[i + 3]` when there's no guarantee `string` has that many elements. In fact, `String_GetEncoding` has no idea how large `string` is since `string` isn't even a string. It isn't a NUL-terminated sequence of `char` values seeing as it could be a chunk of a UTF-16 or UTF-32 file, and these normally have tons of NUL bytes.

Comment: I did not miss it, it is covered by:  _"`String_GetEncoding()` makes no attempt to avoid overrunning the buffer"_.  The part about it not being a valid string is also covered by my point about `fscanf()` and suggestion to read raw bytes with `fread()`.  One follows from the other, I did not see the need to labour the point.

Comment: Ah, I apparently skipped the last paragraph /// Re "*The part about it not being a valid string is also covered by my point about fscanf()*", Not really. fscanf should handle NUL just fine according from what I can read. The problem with fscanf is misinterpreting 0A as a line feed when it isn't. My comment had nothing to do with 0A (or with buffer flow during reading).

Comment: Semantically `fscanf()` is not defined for multibyte characters, even if it happens to work, it is a bad idea.  Semantically what is needed is the raw byte data, not a string.

Comment: It's very well defined. fscanf reads until 0A (on an ASCII-based system). Which is garbage here. It would work for UTF-8, but not UTF-16 (either) or UTF-32

Comment: @ikegami : I think we are in volent agreement - is that not what I said? _"fscanf() works with single byte characters"_?  I take the point that that UTF-8 is not single byte, but that is rather academic.  The purpose of this code is to detect encoding so the input method cannot be encoding specific.

Comment: We both agree that `fscanf` shouldn't be used here, if that's what you mean.